# Check If Someone Send Link + code discord.py rewrite

Tags: python

I want To Check If Someone Send Link + code

like this link

````
```
https://pastebin.com/gD0KD6u4
```
````

after the last / is the code
As if the code is: gD0KD6u4

Comment: Just reverse the string find first '/' then crop the sub-string then reverse cropped sub-string

Comment: Hey @Ikibir,
I am new in python and i am still learning, can you explain this with code please, it will be very considerate from you.
Thank you for answered me

Comment: How is this relevant to discord.py?

Comment: @Harmon758 I just changed the tags sorry for this mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code I believe this would be helpful.

```
link = 'https://pastebin.com/gD0KD6u4'
# reverse the string
reverse_link = link[::-1]
print(reverse_link)
position = reverse_link.find('/')
code_link = reverse_link[:position]
#reverse code
print(code_link)
code_link = code_link[::-1]
print(code_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use rpartition():

```
url = 'https://pastebin.com/gD0KD6u4'
decompose = url.rpartition('/')
url = decompose[0]
code = decompose[-1]

print(url, code)
```